# How to handle backend API request for create-react-app bootstrapped app which is build and ran using "serve-s build" on AWS ec2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have `create-react-app` bootstrapped application which I build and then serve it to the static server using `serve-s build`. The React app is running on `http://locahost:3000`.

This app talks to my backend REST API(using `java`) which is running on `http://locahost:8080`.

Inside my React application, I have set `axios.default.baseURL=http://localhost:8085/api`.

Everything is fine on the localhost on my system. The React app talks to `http://localhost:8085/api/xyz` for CRUD operations and everything works great.

Now I have to deploy the project on AWS EC2 instance. The MySQL and REST API got deployed and rest API there is running on same instance on the port `8085` as `http://locahost:8085`. I have Apache server configured which sends the hostname(www.myxyzwebsite.com) to the `http://locahost:3000` on the server. Everything is fine till now. The home page is visible on the browser.

Now, when the React app tries to communicate to the REST API from the browser, it is sending the request to the `http://locahost:8085`. Obviously, now the browser looks for some service running on port `8085` on my system and it couldn't find. Ideally, the request should go to the server with my hostname(www.myxyzwebsite.com/api/users/puspen). How to make this REST API call looks like an actual call like `www.myxyzwebsite.com/users/pusp`?

NOTE: Please note that this is not a server-side-rendered application.

Comment: Set the environment values for the production mode where it point to the API URL where it is hosted.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi the AWS IP? Actually both frondend and backend are hosted on same EC2 instance